# Android Studio - setQuery not working upon first search

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-emulator, logcat

I am working on a Chinese dictionary-based android application. I'm using handleIntent for the original search from a different activity. The plan is to print those results and also keeping the query in the search bar.

My problem is the query disappears upon changing to the results activity but every other search after the first has the query in the search bar (from this I assume onNewIntent is working but not HandleIntent). It is doing the searches I just want the query to stay in the search bar.

I have used the debugger to make sure the query is being carried through the function by printing the variable and it performs the task without issue but after trying to use setQuery the whole thing crashes on the emulator.

The logcat reads this:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'void
> android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setQuery(java.lang.CharSequence,
> boolean)' on a null object reference
> at celadondragon.com.activities

```
    //Handles the original search from a different activity
@Override
protected void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    //boolean mybool = Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction());
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        final String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        searchDictionary(query);

        searchView.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Important! Make sure searchView has been initialized
                // and referenced to the correct (current) SearchView.
                // Config changes (e.g. screen rotation) may make the
                // variable value null.
                searchView.setQuery(query, false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code in the description as a snippet with ```code```  links to images can brake.

Comment: Did it thank you for the tip!